# Show a huge number of data in DevExpress GridView

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a DevExpress Grid View with 3000 lines and each line has 10 as detail (it means when the grid load I have 30000 items to load)

It takes a long time to load all of the data, so is there any way to show for example 100 line, and when the user use the automatic filter I show the desired rows?.

**Example** http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/filtering/filterrow.aspx

I tried to use the Skip and Take (using LINQ) but it's not really what I'm looking for, in addition to that I would like to use the automatic filter of the grid.

```
public static BindingList<patient> getObjectUsingLinq(string sql = "", int skipCount  = 0, int takeCount = 0)
        {
            var gsData = GetDataContext();
            var query = (from q in gsData.patient 
                        orderby q.nom 
                        select q);

            return new BindingList<patient>(LinqHelper.DoSortPaginate(query, "", skipCount, takeCount).ToList());

        }
```

and to bind this to the Grid I call

```
listPatient = Patients.getObjectUsingLinq();
myGrid.DataSource = listPatient ;
```

Comment: Show us your code before we can take a look. It should be very fast if it is only 3000 rows

Comment: How does the `DoSortPaginate` implementation look, what is the `takeCount` used when it is slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to display a large amount of records in a GridControl, you can use **server data-binding modes** (synchronous or [asynchronous](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8893)). These are specifically designed to work with large sets of data consisting of more than 50,000 records.
Take a look at [Server Mode concepts](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398) to start with these modes.
With XtraGrid and LINQ you can start from here:
[Server Mode: Binding to a Data Source Using 'LINQ to SQL Classes'](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4057)

P.S. The [Data Source Configuration Wizard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16633) simplifies the process of binding a data-aware DevExpress control (such as GridControl) to a data source